# require ibm_db specified module could not be found

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ibm-midrange

I’m trying to install the “ibm_db” gem and verify the installation. I’m running on Windows 7 and I’m trying to use 32bit for everything. The database that I need to connect to is DB2 on an IBM iSeries. Below are the steps I’m using so far.

```
•   gem install “ibm_db”
•   irb
•   require “ibm_db”
```

I get the following results:

```
c:\Users\Bob\RubymineProjects\beginruby>gem install ibm_db
Fetching: ibm_db-2.5.11-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed ibm_db-2.5.11-x86-mingw32
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for ibm_db-2.5.11-x86-mingw32...
Installing RDoc documentation for ibm_db-2.5.11-x86-mingw32...

c:\Users\Bob\RubymineProjects\beginruby>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.2.9, 3.2.7, 3.2.3, 3.1.8, 3.0.12, 3.0.1)
actionpack (3.2.9, 3.2.7, 3.2.3, 3.1.8, 3.0.12, 3.0.1)
activemodel (3.2.9, 3.2.7, 3.2.3, 3.1.8, 3.0.12, 3.0.1)
activerecord (3.2.9, 3.2.7, 3.2.3, 3.1.8, 3.0.12, 3.0.1)
activeresource (3.2.9, 3.2.7, 3.2.3, 3.1.8, 3.0.12, 3.0.1)
activesupport (3.2.9, 3.2.7, 3.2.3, 3.1.8, 3.0.12, 3.0.1)
addressable (2.3.2)
annotate (2.5.0, 2.4.1.beta1, 2.4.0)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
arel (3.0.2, 2.2.3, 2.0.10, 1.0.1)
autotest (4.4.6, 4.3.2)
autotest-fsevent (0.2.8)
autotest-growl (0.2.16)
autotest-rails (4.1.2)
autotest-rails-pure (4.1.2, 4.1.0)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1 x86-mingw32)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
bootstrap-sass (2.2.1.1, 2.0.0)
bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.9, 0.0.6)
builder (3.1.4, 3.0.4, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.2.3, 1.0.22)
capybara (2.0.1, 2.0.0, 1.1.3, 1.1.2)
childprocess (0.3.6)
coderay (1.0.8)
coffee-rails (3.2.2, 3.1.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
columnize (0.3.6)
cucumber (1.2.1)
cucumber-rails (1.3.0, 1.2.1)
database_cleaner (0.9.1, 0.7.0)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.1.5)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
erubis (2.7.0, 2.6.6)
excon (0.16.10)
execjs (1.4.0)
factory_girl (4.1.0, 2.3.2, 1.3.3)
factory_girl_rails (4.1.0, 1.4.0, 1.0)
faker (1.1.2, 1.0.1, 0.3.1)
ffi (1.2.0 x86-mingw32, 1.1.5 x86-mingw32)
gherkin (2.11.5 x86-mingw32)
gravatar_image_tag (1.1.3, 1.0.0.pre2, 0.1.0)
guard (1.5.4)
guard-rspec (2.3.1, 2.3.0, 0.5.5)
guard-spork (1.4.0, 0.3.2)
heroku (2.33.3, 2.33.2, 2.33.1)
heroku-api (0.3.7, 0.3.6)
hike (1.2.1)
hpricot (0.8.6)
i18n (0.6.1, 0.5.0, 0.4.2)
ibm_db (2.5.11 x86-mingw32)
io-console (0.3)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.1.4, 2.1.3)
json (1.7.5, 1.5.4)
launchy (2.1.2)
libwebsocket (0.1.7.1, 0.1.6.1, 0.1.6)
linecache19 (0.5.13, 0.5.12)
listen (0.6.0, 0.5.3)
lumberjack (1.0.2)
mail (2.5.3, 2.5.2, 2.4.4, 2.3.3, 2.2.19)
method_source (0.8.1)
mime-types (1.19)
minitest (4.3.3, 4.3.2, 2.5.1)
multi_json (1.5.0, 1.4.0, 1.3.7, 1.2.0)
netrc (0.7.7)
nokogiri (1.5.5 x86-mingw32)
pg (0.14.1 x86-mingw32, 0.12.2 x86-mingw32)
polyglot (0.3.3)
pry (0.9.10 i386-mingw32)
rack (1.4.1, 1.3.6, 1.2.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-mount (0.8.3, 0.6.14)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2, 0.5.7)
rails (3.2.9, 3.0.12, 3.0.1)
railties (3.2.9, 3.2.7, 3.2.3, 3.1.8, 3.0.12, 3.0.1)
rake (10.0.3, 10.0.2, 10.0.1, 0.9.2.2)
rbx-require-relative (0.0.9)
rdiscount (1.6.8)
rdoc (3.12, 3.9.4)
RedCloth (4.2.9 x86-mingw32)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rspec (2.12.0, 2.6.0)
rspec-core (2.6.4)
rspec-expectations (2.12.0, 2.6.0)
rspec-mocks (2.12.0, 2.10.1, 2.9.0, 2.6.0)
rspec-rails (2.12.0, 2.6.1)
ruby-debug-base19x (0.11.30.pre10)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.17.beta14)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
sass (3.3.0.alpha.16, 3.2.4, 3.2.3)
sass-rails (3.2.5, 3.2.4, 3.1.6)
selenium-webdriver (2.27.1, 2.26.0)
slop (3.3.3)
spork (0.9.2, 0.9.0.rc8 x86-mingw32)
sprockets (2.8.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.1, 2.1.3, 2.0.4)
sqlite3 (1.3.6 x86-mingw32, 1.3.5 x86-mingw32, 1.3.4 x86-mingw32)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
sys-uname (0.9.0 x86-mingw32)
thor (0.16.0, 0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.35)
uglifier (1.3.0, 1.2.3)
webrat (0.7.3, 0.7.1)
websocket (1.0.4, 1.0.3, 1.0.2)
will_paginate (3.0.3, 3.0.pre2)
win32-process (0.7.0)
win32console (1.3.2 x86-mingw32)
xpath (1.0.0, 0.1.4)
ZenTest (4.8.3, 4.8.2)

c:\Users\Bob\RubymineProjects\beginruby>irb
irb(main):001:0> gem 'ibm_db'
=> true

rb(main):002:0> require 'ibm_db'
LoadError: 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby
/gems/1.9.1/gems/ibm_db-2.5.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mswin32/rb19x/ibm_db.so
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:i
n `rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ibm_db-2.5.11-x86-mingw32/lib/m
swin32/ibm_db.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ibm_db-2.5.11-x86-mingw32/lib/i
bm_db.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:i
n `require'
        from (irb):2
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0>
```

Comment: did you read this thread: https://groups.google.com/group/ibm_db/browse_thread/thread/880753ad99d399f7/9410202178da063b?#9410202178da063b

Comment: Thanks, Phoet.  I looked at that. There are some things mentioned there that lead me to believe it does not apply in my case. I'm not using python or informix and that issue does not appear to be resolved. No where in the information I'm reading about installing ibm_db for DB2 on my iSeries for rails and/or ruby does it mention anything about ibm_db...egg. I've also downloaded and installed IBM's Data Server Driver Package. IBM's instructions for installing ibm_db for ruby says that changing environment variables on Windows is not required. Any more ideas would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put in your irb console (windows):

```
require 'mswin32/ibm_db'

conn = IBM_DB::connect("DATABASE","db2admin","password")
```

Of course, you can do any operation with this connection from irb for test your ibm_db gem, for example if it working correctly.